# loop through and .replace using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of url extensions that i want to string replace using regex so that both upper and lower case is captured like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\.net/i,"")
.replace(/\.com/i,"")
.replace(/\.org/i,"")
.replace(/\.net/i,"")
.replace(/\.int/i,"")
.replace(/\.edu/i,"")
.replace(/\.gov/i,"")
.replace(/\.mil/i,"")
.replace(/\.arpa/i,"")
.replace(/\.ac/i,"")
.replace(/\.ad/i,"")
.replace(/\.ae/i,"")
.replace(/\.af/i,"");
```

When i try to clean this up using arrays and loops like so, i get an error.  Can anyone help me with syntax please

```
var arr = [ "net","com","org","net","int","edu","gov","mil","arpa","ac","ad","ae"];

str = str.replace(/\.com/i,"")
for(ii==0;ii<=arr.length;ii++){
  .replace('/\.'+arr[ii]+'/i',"") // i know this '/\.' and '/i' should not be a string but how would i write it?
} 
.replace(/\.af/i,"");
```

Comment: `/myregex/` and `"/myregex/"` are not the same thing.

Comment: Also, you can't do `.replace` without a string to call it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `RegExp` object. You also need to apply `.replace` to the string, and assign the result.

```
for (ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
    str = str.replace(new Regexp('\\.' + arr[ii], 'i'));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just do like this instead of running replace multiple times in a loop:

```
str = str.replace(/\.(com|net|org|gov|edu|ad|ae|ac|int)/gi, '');
```